# Can't delete Azure AD Tenant even though empty

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

When trying to delete my tenant I get this message:

[image]

However if I go to look at enterprise applications its completely empty, so can't delete any. What can I do to delete this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need check with `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal`. Please ensure the cmdlet return null.

If some application SPs are  in your directory, please use the following command to delete them.

```
Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal -objectid [enter object id here]
```

More information about this please refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kennethteo/2017/09/19/deleting-azure-ad-tenant/).

If you have multiple service principal, you could use a loop delete them. Just a example.

```
$sps=Get-AzureADServicePrincipal
ForEach ($sp in $sps) {
    Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal -objectid $sp.objectid
}
```

Comment: managed to start removing ServicePrincipals, but how do you know which are required? Do I just have to try and remove each... ? thats my day gone

Comment: @Green_qaue Sorry for the later response, you need delete all service principals, just use `Get-AzureADServicePrincipal` to get service principal object id, then use a loop to delete them with `Remove-AzureADServicePrincipal`

Comment: Sorry I still have not have time to try it, I will let you know.